# Why is my polymorphic association nil while the _id and _type fields are not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing some tests for my Rails project. I've come to writing some tests around a polymorphic association, for which I have defined a fixture. However, when I try to access the polymorphically associated field on that fixture, it returns `nil`.

The strange part is that while the field itself is `nil`, the `_id` and `_type` fields that describe it are not.

This is the model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(is_deleted: false) }

  belongs_to :post, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

(In case it wasn't obvious, the `post` association is the polymorphic.)

This is the action in the controller that I'm trying to test:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def update
    if @comment.update comment_params

      puts @comment.post.nil?
      puts @comment.post_id.nil?
      puts @comment.post_type.nil?

      if @comment.post_type == 'Question'
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :questions, :action => :show, :id => @comment.post.id)
      else
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :questions, :action => :show, :id => @comment.post.question.id)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment failed to update."
      if @comment.post_type == 'Question'
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :questions, :action => :show, :id => @comment.post.id)
      else
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :questions, :action => :show, :id => @comment.post.question.id)
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_type, :post_id)
    end

  # ...

end
```

The test itself looks like this:

```
test "should update existing comment" do
  sign_in users(:standard_user)
  patch :update, :id => comments(:one).id, :comment => { :content => "ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ" }
  assert_not_nil assigns(:comment)
  assert_not_nil assigns(:comment).post
  assert_response(302)
end
```

And, finally, the fixture for that existing comment (`comments(:one)`) is:

```yaml
one:
  user: standard_user
  post: one (Answer)
  content: ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR
```

Both the `standard_user` User fixture and the `one` Answer fixture are correctly defined.

Running the test gives me this error:

```
  2) Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_should_update_existing_comment:
NoMethodError: undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:50:in `update'
    test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:CommentsControllerTest>'
```

The three log lines near the top of the `update` action output `true \n false \n false` - i.e. that the `post` field is `nil`, but that `post_id` and `post_type` are not.

Why is this? What can I do to fix it? I have no ID fields defined in my fixtures YAML, and I'd prefer not to have to specify the IDs (unless it can be done with ERB).

This is the entirety of the Answers fixture that the Comments depend on:

```yaml
one:
  body: ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ
  score: 0
  question: one
  user: standard_user

two:
  body: ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ
  score: 0
  question: one
  user: editor
```

That in turn depends on this Question fixture:

```yaml
one:
  title: ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ
  body: ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ ABCDEF GHIJKL MNOPQR STUVWX YZ
  tags:
    - ABCDEF
    - GHIJKL
    - MNOPQR
  score: 0
  user: standard_user
```

It seems that this issue is caused by there being no Answer fixtures in the database when the comments tests happen (so the call to `@comment.post` returns nil, and `@comment.post.question` or `@comment.post.id` raises a `NoMethodError`). However, the test helper file calls `fixtures :all`, so I don't see why those fixtures aren't loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when ActiveRecord couldn't find the polymorphic association.

Even though the `post_id` and `post_type` have values, but `Answer` with id by `comment.post_id` could not be found, it will just return `nil` when you call `comment.post`.

Could you paste your `answers.yml` fixture? I think you might have put an id in it accidentally.

EDIT:

I found the bug in your project. You didn't add default value for is_deleted in answers and comments tables, so you won't find the correct record since their is_deleted is NULL actually. My advice would be: never use default_scope, you can always have another better solution than that.

Comment: Posted both the dependent fixtures in the question.

Comment: Could you try to print `@comment.post_id` and `Answer.all.map(&:id)` ?

Comment: The former prints `980190962`, the latter prints `[]`.

Comment: Then that's the problem, there are no answers in the database. I would suggest you to investigate why answers fixtures are not saved into the database.

Comment: That's what's confusing me. The fixtures should be loaded - the test helper calls `fixtures :all`.

Comment: I setup a new Rails codebase with your schema, but couldn't reproduce your problem. You could run the test by `bundle exec ruby -Itest test/models/answer_test.rb` and try it.

Comment: The entire project is available to clone from Git [here](https://gitlab.com/ArtOfCode/qpixel) if you want an exact copy.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I found the bug in your project. You didn't add default value for `is_deleted` in `answers` and `comments` tables, so you won't find the correct record since their `is_deleted` is `NULL` actually. My advice would be: never use `default_scope`, you can always have another better solution than that.

Comment: Yep, just tested and confirmed. If you'd like to add that to your answer, I'll give it an accept as well as an upvote.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Added to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is absolutely correct and thank you for pointing this out. Took me awhile to figure this one out. Additionally, if you are using `id` values but for some reason are not setting the `id` of the parent record correctly, this can lead to false negatives where it can find a record (and be valid) but not be the correct record. Scary stuff!